clipboard content doesn't modifiy html input files array, why?
I have a form in which I let the user add up to 5 files in a way that I only show one <input type="file"> and if the user do put a file at the <input> then I update the form adding another input and so on.  It works pretty well when I use the file picker and choose a file. But now I'm trying to add an option so the user can just CTRL+V an image clipboard content directly into the <input> field and then update the form as said before. I also added a loop verifying if the input fields do have content so the user don't update, like, the 0th input and then a new input emerges for no necessity. And that's the point that making my code fail as shown below:
EDIT I've just added an entire HTML file that simulates the issue:
EDIT 2 This issue didn't happen under Chromium based Brave browser, I can simulate it under Firefox
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form-post" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/someroute">
        <!-- other inputs... -->
        <div id="form-post-file-input-div">
            <div class="form-post-file-input-box">
                <input class="novo-post-form-item form-post-file-input" name="arquivos[]" type="file" onchange="addNovoInputFile(this, 5)">
            </div>    
        </div>
        </form>
        
        <script>
var addNovoInputFile = function(elem, max){
    fileInputs = $('.form-post-file-input');

    // When this loop is reached from a copypaste event, the content of fileInputs[0].files is empty
    // this doesn't happen when I just select a file from filepicker 
    for(var i=0; i < fileInputs.length; i++)
    {
        if(fileInputs[i].files.length === 0)
            return;
    }
    // I put this loop so I don't update the form in case, for example, if the user keeps updating a file at the 0th <input>
    // but maybe my solution is just changing the logic of this loop
    
    if(fileInputs.length >= max || elem.files.length === 0)
        return;
    
    var novoInput = "<div class=\"form-post-file-input-box\">";
    novoInput += "<input class=\"novo-post-form-item form-post-file-input\" name=\"arquivos[]\" type=\"file\" onchange=\"addNovoInputFile(this, " + max + ")\">";
    novoInput += "</div>"
    
    $(novoInput).appendTo(".form-post #form-post-file-input-div");
};

// New event I just added in order to fill the input with a printscreen content in the clipboard
window.addEventListener('paste', e => {
    let inputs = document.getElementsByName('arquivos[]');
    let inputToChange = inputs[inputs.length-1];

    if(e.clipboardData.files.length > 0){
        inputToChange.files = e.clipboardData.files;
        addNovoInputFile(inputToChange, 5);
    }
});


        </script>
</body>
</html>

What exactly is happening is that when I run CTRL+V the second time the 0th element from the list returned by $('.form-post-file-input') has the .files array empty and the 1st has the content from the clipboard. Why does that happen since when I typed CTRL+V for the first time I did fill the content of .files (in addEventListener) and the proof for that is that when I submit the form the 0th file is uploaded to the server... but the .files is empty... I don't understand why specially because this doesn't happen when I choose files from the file picker.

Can you explain what exactly about this "fails"? I am getting the file name of the pasted file shown next to the last input field, same as when I click the button and chose a file from the dialog.

I can't reproduce what you are saying, in a Chromium-based browser. https://jsfiddle.net/43p8vc70/ - works fine, pasting a file adds a new input field. Do you have this issue in a specific browser?

@C3roe it works only the first field, u can see that it doesn't add up to 5 like when using file picker (this in firefox)

@Yogi indeed you are right, I solved this issue by changing inputToChange.files = e.clipboardData.files to inputToChange.files = structuredClone(e.clipboardData.files) when the code is ran under firefox (https://jsfiddle.net/hrdfvuLk/)... however it didn't worked when I submited the form but I guess this is for another question

The cause is use of return; statement which will exit the whole function instead of for loop thus it won't create another input picker.
You must use break; instead:
    // When this loop is reached from a copypaste event, the content of fileInputs[0].files is empty
    // this doesn't happen when I just select a file from filepicker 
    for(var i=0; i < fileInputs.length; i++)
    {
        if(fileInputs[i].files.length === 0)
            return;
    }

to
    // When this loop is reached from a copypaste event, the content of fileInputs[0].files is empty
    // this doesn't happen when I just select a file from filepicker 
    for(var i=0; i < fileInputs.length; i++)
    {
        if(fileInputs[i].files.length === 0)
            break; // Change
    }

it worked in chromium based browsers because fileInputs[i].files.length was not 0 over there.
